# Клиент -android, сервер -java app

Tags: android, сокет, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста! Есть Клиент под Android и сервер на java на pc - когда запускаешь с эмулятора - все работает - сообщения передаются. Когда запускаешь приложение на android устройстве - при нажатии на кнопку отправить всё вылетает.
Очень нужна ваша помощь.

Код Клиента:

```
package com.example.client;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import com.example.client.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;    
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket client;
private PrintWriter printwriter;
private EditText textField;
private Button button;
private String messsage;
String ip="192.168.0.80";
int port=80;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textout); 
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

messsage = textField.getText().toString(); 
Socket client =null;
textField.setText("");      
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream= null;
DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

try {

 client = new Socket("192.168.0.80", 80);
 client.setSoTimeout(100);
 dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
 dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
 dataOutputStream.writeUTF(messsage);

} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Got an IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}
}
});
}
}
```

Comment: нельзя с gui потока лазить в сеть. Это нужно делать в отдельном потоке (или сервисе).

Comment: KoVadim, объясните пожалуйста подробней...  спасибо вам

Comment: Ребят подскажите пожалуйста, как запустить в отдельном потоке? Я понимаю как пишется, но что именно из моего кода запускать в нем.
 
Thread myThread = new Thread (new Runnable() {
  
  @Override
  public void run() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  }
 );
 myThread.start();

Comment: Скинь код из своего Манифест.xml ато у меня почемуто нехочет конектитса к серверу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы производите коннект с сервером в главном потоке, на реальном устройстве в новых версиях Android SDK это выкидывает исключение, а на эмуляторе работает.

Вам нужно создать поток `Thread` или `Runnable` и вынести всю логику коннекта и связи на этот поток.

**Обновление**

Вот этот код внесите в run():

```
 client = new Socket("192.168.0.80", 80); 
 client.setSoTimeout(100); 
 dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()); 
 dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream()); 
 dataOutputStream.writeUTF(messsage);
```

Comment: Barmaley, Спасибо вам за ваш ответ. Не понимаю что именно из моего кода внести в поток. Пытался по разному, ничего не выходит...

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Barmaley, Всё так и сделал. Да теперь не вылетает на реальном устройстве, но пропала связь с сервером.

Comment: @DDA04 многопоточное программирование это вам не бином Ньютона... разбирайтесь :)

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Все заработало! Разобрался!

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте следующие статьи

- [Отзывчивое Android-приложение или 1001 способ загрузить картинку](http://habrahabr.ru/company/eastbanctech/blog/192998/)
- [Процессы и потоки в Android: пишем AsyncTask правильно](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124484/)
- [«Правильный» html парсинг](http://habrahabr.ru/post/115127/)